# Can't add record with ID from another table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ticket-system

I have a database which functions similarly to a "help desk" system - an outside user creates a request ticket, then a consultant will use the database for various tracking and reporting.

There is a form that the consultant uses to display and work with the end user request. They select an existing record (request ticket) from a combo box. The form then populates with the information of the request, which the consultant can edit if needed.

I then have a series of buttons on this form that the consultant can use to open different forms (worksheets) and enter data in each one. These are all optional and will vary based on the type of request.

These worksheets all populate the "Consulting" table, while the initial requests are in a "Request" table. There is only one record in the "Consulting" table per record in "Request" (1:1 relationship).

Here is the code I have to open the forms (worksheets):

```
Private Sub ButtonGap_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "Gap Analysis", acNormal, , "[ID] = " & Me!ID, acFormEdit, acDialog
End Sub
```

This only partially works. If there is existing information in the "Consulting" table with an ID that corresponds to the ID from "Request" (what they selected in the combo box at the start), the worksheet will open pre-populated and editable. Great!

But... if there is no existing information in the "Consulting" table with an ID that corresponds to the ID from "Request", the worksheet opens blank, to a new record. This record autonumbers from where the "Consulting" table left off. This creates a problem if several requests have come in - we are not always working on them in order, so the new record ID in "Consulting" does not match the existing record from the "Request".

I'm sure it's something incredibly simple I'm overlooking. Can anyone help?

Comment: What keys are in the Request and Consulting table? Is Request.ID an AutoNumber? Can there be multiple Consulting records for any Request record? It's ok to have AutoNumber ID's for each table, but you need to be able to relate the Consult back to the Request.

Comment: Both "Request" and "Consulting" use numerical keys with autonumber (both called ID). There is a 1=1 relationship - there will only be one record in Consulting for each record in Request. I'm trying to use the key from Request to create/update the record in Consulting.

Comment: If you insist upon using that key relationship - and using AutoNumber - then you may never get it 100% correct. Your best bet is to modify the code where the 'Request' is created to automatically create an 'empty' Consulting record at the same time. Depending on how many users enter requests or add consulting records, you could still get out of sync by milliseconds. To be fool-proof, you would need to lock the Request table while the add is done and then create the consulting record before releasing the lock. Or create a consulting key field that is not AutoNumber, but equals the Request key.

Comment: You say your two tables have a 1:1 relationship but have you actually set this relationship up? If so which data links the two fields? Also if there is only ever one consulting record per request record then why do they need to be in separate tables?

Comment: I'm not insisting on using anything, just trying to make this work. How would I create an empty record in the Consulting table when a request is submitted? I've been trying to do this with an append query, but I can't get it to work either.

Comment: Yes, the relationship is set. The data that should match is the ID (request with ID comes in, creates the appropriate record in consulting), but it would be useful to pre-populate the worksheets with information from the request as well. I guess everything could be in one table, but once I figure this part out, there are two more tables to link, another with a 1:1, and the final with a 1:many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a way to do this, it appears. If I missed something, please let me know! I don't want to break anything else. :)

I created a query to find the unmatched records, giving me a list of all IDs from Request without a matching ID in Consulting.

From there, I based an append query on these results, to append just the missing IDs to Consulting.

That query runs when the Request form is submitted:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Add Blank Consulting"
End Sub
```

Now my worksheets on the Consulting form are populating with the correct ID!

Comment: Something seems strange to me. If you have two tables, regardless if they are related, each with an AutoNumber field, and you add 5 records to T1 before you add anything to T2, the first add to T2 will result in a value of 1. Are you sure the relationship is built on the AutoNumber fields in T1 and T2? If mine was the 5th Request entered, but the first one worked on, my Consulting ID would be 1 and not 5.

Comment: I had to switch the autonumber field in consulting to number for it to work. Is that going to cause me problems later on?

Comment: Assuming your 'ID' field in the Consulting table is now a 'long integer' (same as an AutoNumber) and you set that as your Primary Key (no dups allowed or needed), you can relate the Request table and all will be fine. When you store a record in Consulting, you just set the ID to be whatever your Request ID is.  It's good.

Comment: Great, thank you for explaining things so well that I could work something out!